# is it possible to add cells or delete cells using codes in jupyter notebook?

Tags: for-loop, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, cell

is it possible to use code to add or delete cells in jupyter notebook?

For example: can we use a for loop in range of 10 that creates 10 cells and perhaps executes something in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the code is provided in a discussion in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2660).

You could use the following code to programmatically append 10 new code cells below the current cell.

```py
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

# create 10 cells
for i in range(10):
    display(Javascript('''
        let cell = IPython.notebook.insert_cell_{}("{}")
        cell.set_text("{}")
        '''.format('below', 'code', "print('Hello World!')")));
    add_cell('print(\'Hello World\')')
```

If you want to execute one, or possibly all of them, you could use the following code.

```py
# execute the 3rd cell of the notebook
display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_cell(3)'))
```

The above will execute the third cell in the notebook. You could loop over the indices that you want to execute.